# How to get all view-scope object?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I'm trying to log all output view-scope object that an Action is passing to a View (as is a JSP).

I would like to print all of them **from the action** itself. I mean: at the end of the action execution, just before the 'ActionResult' return statement.

For example, I would like to do something like the following:

```
public class HelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport
{
    private String errorMessage;

    public String getErrorMessage()
    {
        return this.errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage)
    {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String execute()
    {
        this.setErrorMessage("Error!!!");

        Enumeration keys = ServletActionContext.getResponse().getParameterNames();
        StringBuilder strB5r = new StringBuilder();
        strB5r.append("Response parameters : ");
        while (keys.hasMoreElements())
        {
          String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
          strB5r.append("[").append(key).append(": ").append(ServletActionContext.getResponse().getAttribute(key).toString()).append("]");
        }

        System.out.println(strB5r.toString());

        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I would like to see the output in cosole as:

```
Response parameters : [errorMessage : Error!!!]
```

The problem is that

> ServletActionContext.getResponse().getParameterNames();

doesn't exists, contrary to what we can do with the request:

> ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameterNames();

How can we do to list all output view-scope object from the action?

Ps. I prefer to don't use the java reflection for many reasons: the main is performance.

Comment: No such scope is available. The question unclear. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Struts2 allows to pass object to the view if you declare a variable and its getter and setter in an Action. Now: how can I get all the object passed to the view without using the java reflection? Thank you

Comment: @0bot The object passed to the view is the action itself.

Comment: (IMO the question is clear-enough; OP wants to access what's available in the view layer, which is the value stack. That the OP doesn't know this is implied by the question, and it's an easy-enough misconception to clear up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only reflection will work.

Before the view layer the action itself is pushed onto the value stack.

The S2 tags (and JSP EL via the request wrapper) use OGNL to retrieve values from the value stack. OGNL uses reflection. E.g., `${errorMessage}` is using reflection to retrieve the value from the action which is on the top of the value stack.

The values aren't there individually, they're "embedded" in the objects placed onto the value stack.

You'd need to get the value stack *and* the action, iterate over the stack content, and retrieve all publicly-accessible values (methods and props) via reflection to get the stack *and* accessible content. (I don't recall if the rest of the stack content is already available in the action or if more content is added later. This also doesn't take into account any other mechanisms that would modify the stack pre-view.)

This is what the S2 debug tag does on the view layer; you might just use that instead.

Comment: Ok, you have clarified many aspects, but I have a doubt:

I know that a variable passed to the view can be accessed in 3 ways:

- s2 tags (e.g.     <s:property value="nameVariable" /> )

- ognl (e.g. ${nameVariable} )

- jsp tags (eg.  <%=request.getAttribute("nomeVariabile"); %> 

The last one makes me think that all variable are wrapped and then inserted into the request-attributes map, there is something that I missed? Thank you

Comment: @0bot Yes. The S2 request wrapper "normalizes" access to the value stack and regularly-scoped attributes (request, application, etc.). If a value is not found in the value stack then the servlet spec scopes are searched as normal.